# VB using WCF: Cannot find endpoint element via com wrapped C# dll

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dll, vb6

I have been getting this error "Could not find endpoint with name... " when I try running my Vb6 application that consumes .Net dll referenced with WCF service. Am sure this has to be something that needs to be dealt with config file. Since the config file in dll is looking absolutely fine and has endpoints configured properly, am suspecting I may need to have a app.config file for VB6 application since that is the caller application which ideally should consume WCf service via C# dll. It would be great if someone could through a thought on how this needs to be dealt.

Comment: You answered your question by yourself. The executing application needs the config, not the dll. Next time just try it first....

Comment: Absolutely right. But the difficulty am facing is on the configuration file for VB. I have placed the configuration file in the location where the VB6 application is getting launched. The format is VB6.exe.config, but am ending up in getting the same error as earlier. Is there something that am missing

Comment: I'm not really proficient in vb6, but maybe [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719108(v=vs.71).aspx) will shed some light.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rabban but I couldn't resolve that error. Looks like VB fails to recognize the config file that I have placed.

Comment: Did you wrote the c# assembly or can you change it? Then you could give all dependent data as parameters to your assembly.

Comment: Since executing assembly needs the config file as you rightly pointed out. I tried manually filling the config data in the com wrapped C# dll before the service instance is created and passed in the binding data as well as EndPointAddress. This worked fine for me.

Comment: I'm glad it worked ;) Please add your comment as answer and mark it as answered. So other people with similar problems can find it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer for this. Based on the approach followed VB6->C# DLL->WCF Service, the WCF service would search config file for the executing assembly which basically is VB6 exe. This would result in an error "Cannot find endpoint element...". So in order to resolve this, I manually tried setting the binding properties in the com wrapped C# dll and passed in binding object along with EndPointAddress to the constructor of the service on instance creation. Below is the code snippet that sets the binding properties similar to that of config file.

```
        Binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        Binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        Binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        Binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        Binding.AllowCookies = false;
        Binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
        Binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
        Binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
        Binding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        Binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
        Binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
```

This might be one of the possible ways to resolve this issue if someone is facing similar issue.